# RemoveAll does not remove the records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to delete some records based on some condition upon clicking some button.
After deleting these records only, I will be inserting new data.

```
 dbContext.AdviserFeeDetailReports.AsEnumerable().ToList()
     .RemoveAll(x => x.PracticeId == superFund.CompanyID 
             && x.SuperFundId == superFund.SuperFundId);

 dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I am wondering why it does not remove the relevant records from the table. There is no exception raised, above two lines get executed. But the records are still there in DbContext as well as in the database.

Comment: Why do you add these? *.AsEnumerable().ToList()*

Comment: When calling `AsEnumerable` you´re putting the complete data into memory making every modification to your data just locally.

Comment: To make the list enumerable. Otherwise, RemoveAll() method is not available. I even tried without AsEnumerable(), that is only with ToList(). That did not work either

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are removing from the list, not from `AdviserFreeDetailReports`. Also, the calls `AsEnumerable()` and `ToList()` will pull entire table from the database and put the data in a separate List, is that what you want?

I believe your code will be more efficient this way:

```
var toRemove = dbContext.AdviserFeeDetailReports
    .Where(x => 
        x.PracticeId == superFund.CompanyID && 
        x.SuperFundId == superFund.SuperFundId);

dbContext.AdviserFreeDetailReports.RemoveRange(toRemove);

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

This implementation pulls only the objects you plan to remove, and `DbContext` starts tracking them. The call to `RemoveRange` will mark each of the objects for deletion. Finally, `SaveChanges` will issue `DELETE` statement(s) that will ultimately remove all the selected objects from the database table.